# problem with Virtualbox bridged networking internet access

Tags: windows, linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I installed Virtualbox on Ubuntu and windows xp as geust
i have adsl connection in my ubuntu

in Nat i have internet but in bridge case i dont have internet

in bridged networking i could ping winxp from other machine and in other machine ping winxp too
my ubuntu ip is 192.168.3.20 and
i set 192.168.3.19/24 with out getway and dns

how could access to internet in dridge networking??

Comment: Is 192.168.3.19 the IP address of your router or your other machine?

Comment: its my winxp ip adress

Comment: Then there's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running with Bridged mode networking it is as if the guest OS is a completely separate computer on the network and nothing at all do to with the Host OS.

You should treat the guest as if it were a separate computer and configure the networking accordingly.

The default gateway and DNS settings should point to your Internet router, not the host computer.

Better still, if your using DHCP on your network, use that to configure the guest automatically.